# laravel cron not firing but other crons are firing

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-artisan

I have a ubuntu 18.04 setup and running laravel 5.6 and i have set up the default scheduler in crontab -e

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/crons.txt 2>&1
```

and this is not running

my Kernel code

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\CompletelyReviewInternship',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsers',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersTwo',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersThree',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersFour',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersFive',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersSix',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersSeven',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersEight',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersNine',
        'App\Console\Commands\MigrateUsersTen'
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('review:internship')->hourly();

        $schedule->command('migrate:users')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:userstwo')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:usersthree')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:usersthree')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:usersfour')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:usersfive')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:userssix')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:usersseven')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:userseight')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:usersnine')->dailyAt('17:40');

        $schedule->command('migrate:usersten')->dailyAt('17:40');

    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Please Note :- my commands are firing with php artisan
and i am using nginx as my web server

any advise on this will be advisable

Comment: which cron is not working

Comment: none of them are firing but i did a sample touch and it is working

Comment: Anything in your laravel.log?

Comment: in addition to what @luminoslty said, check your var/log/crons/cron.log file

Comment: I would say - your app is in maintenance mode. Are you sure it's not ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be multiple reasons of that:

- Your application is in maintenance mode. In such case no command will be running unless you use `->evenInMaintenanceMode()` for each command
- You are using time, but time on your machine is different than what you expect so command will be run at some later point. Make sure time is really valid, or try to change time constraints to `->everyMinute()` just to make sure it's not a problem in this case

As a side not - it' not necessary to list all command in `$commands` property if they are in `Commands` directory.

Comment: yes the issue is dailyAt() and when i did everyMinute() it ran so the time was set in UTC and i Reverted to india time but still after changing the server time using sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata it does fire when due and last night i had crons set up as per India time and we are 4-5 hours ahead of UTC so why did it not fire when it became due eventually .. any advise on this will eventually solve my issue.. thank you so far

Comment: @DhavalChheda It's hard to say, you can try to add `log()->info('Current time: '.now()->toDateTimeString());` at the beginning of your `schedule` method and after a few minutes take a look at laravel log what's the date and time in there. Keep in mind that Laravel uses timezone that is set in `config/app.php` file so maybe the problem is that you haven't set valid timezone in this file?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using nginx then u have set user `www-data` in cron tab with super user permission like this

```
* * * * * sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue is with dailyAt() as the cron runs with everyMinute()